# How can I choose a specific value from the API result

Tags: php

My site displays prices for all Dota 2 items from a third-party service.

I get an answer when a list of things is parsed like this:

```
"The Lightning Orchid": {
    "name": "The Lightning Orchid",
    "price": {
        "24_hours": {
            "average": 106.5,
            "median": 106.5,
            "sold": "92",
            "standard_deviation": "3.29",
            "lowest_price": 98.8,
            "highest_price": 115.61
        },
        "7_days": {
            "average": 106.5,
            "median": 107.2,
            "sold": "764",
            "standard_deviation": "3.29",
            "lowest_price": 95.29,
            "highest_price": 115.61
        },
        "opskins_average": 81.28
    },
    "first_sale_date": "1401573600"
},
```

My code which update all prices is:

```
const STEAMP = 'http://dota2.csgobackpack.net/api/GetItemsList/v2/?currency=RUB&no_details=true&details=false';
public static function updatePrices()
{
    if ($data = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::STEAMP)) ?? false) {
        if ($data->success) {
            Storage::disk('local')->put(self::Prices, json_encode([
                'time' => time(),
                'items' => $data->items_list,
            ]));
            return $data->items_list;
        } else {
            \Log::error('Error: ' . $data->message);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        \Log::error('Error updating prices!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I get the lowest price in 24 hours? I try add  `'lowest_price' => $data->lowest_price,` but i start received error `Undefined property: stdClass::$lowest_price`

Comment: Do you want the lowest price of one specific item?  Or the lowest price across the entire set?  `$data` is the top-level object which contains a list of items, and each item contains a list of prices.  As the error indicates, `lowest_price` is not a property of the top-level object.  You need to work your way down to where it exists in the tree.

Comment: i want `lowest_price` for all item's, what i received.you mean i need make for example `if ($data->price) {`? and then write `'lowest_price' => $data->lowest_price,`i?

Comment: Then you're going to have to loop over the `$data->items_list` array, grab the lowest price of each object, compare it to what you have saved as the lowest price (you'll save the first item's lowest price to this variable to start), and if it is lower, save that price as the lowest price, and keep going.

Comment: I'll say it again.  In your current code, `$data` is your _top-level_ object.  It does _not_ represent an individual item.